# How could I except a certain element in arrays those I randomized them using Shuffle function?

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

How could I except a certain element in multidimensional arrays those I randomized them using Shuffle function?

Assume that I have this script:

```
$array = array(
  array("Bird", "Brown", "Bear", "Bangkok", "Bat"),
  array("Carrot", "Cat", "Crispy", "Cross", "Cable"),
  array("All", "Apple", "Adam", "Apart", "Air")
);

array_walk($array, function (&$array) { shuffle($array); });
shuffle($array);
```

That script would give me a shuffled arrays vertically and shuffled elements in each array.

What I need is to except the first element (position 0) for every array, how could I do that, please?

Comment: you mean delete the position 0 of every subarray?

Comment: just remove the first element from each sub-array (`array_shift()`) before shuffling.  Then add that element back in if needed (`array_unshift()`).

Comment: @ Frederico Schardong: Yes, but temporary after the shuffling has been accomplished.

Comment: @ Mike Brant: "Niko" has a similar suggestion as an "Answer", but that might be work for array not a multidimensional array..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious solution is something like this:

```
// Remove and store the first element in a temporary variable
$firstElement = array_shift($array);

// Shuffle the remaining items
shuffle($array);

// Re-add (prepend) the original first item
array_unshift($array, $firstElement);
```

---

This can be easily applied to your specific example:

```
function customShuffle(array &$array) {
    $firstElement = array_shift($array);
    shuffle($array);
    array_unshift($array, $firstElement);
}

$array = array(
  array("Bird", "Brown", "Bear", "Bangkok", "Bat"),
  array("Carrot", "Cat", "Crispy", "Cross", "Cable"),
  array("All", "Apple", "Adam", "Apart", "Air")
);

                                         // vvvvv //
array_walk($array, function (&$array) { customShuffle($array); });
shuffle($array);  // use "customShuffle" as well if needed
```

Comment: How could I do that if I had a multidimensional array, please? I need to shift only the first value of each sub array. Thanks.

Comment: @m.rizeg All you need to do is apply the described pattern to the shuffling - I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: I wish all the best to you.. :)

Comment: Would help me in same subject but with another problem here http://goo.gl/Sbthb .. Thank you.